# A question about integration

Tags: integration

I would like to know if this : $\int dW=W$
is a valid expression and what is its meaning.
I came across it in a statics book where W is a load measured in Newtons.
I can't seem to understand why there are no limits of integration, while W is a specific number of Newtons(force) , not an indedifite integral.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Normally they assume zero initial condition. May you explain in more detail which part of Statics, I might be able to help you. Is it related to distributed load on a beam?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes it is.